# Partial match when look up value is lengthier than corresponding value in a table or a range

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, filtering, vlookup

I have table as below. In first column name of the company and in next column corresponding country.
The look up value of company name is not exact match in this case
The company name from table is a subset of the look up value.

Reference Table as below:

[image]

The output expected is as follows:

[image]

I tried using formula`=VLOOKUP(LEFT(B14,LEN(B14)-4),$H$2:$I$4,2,FALSE)`

but it only help solve first entry and not for others. The output I got with above formula is as below:

[image]

Request help in sorting this issue. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try the following:

```
=INDEX(I:I,SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(FIND(H$3:H$4,B14))*ROW(H$3:H$4)))
```

However, this might be troublesome when you anticipate a word can be a sub-string inside another, eventually giving wrong results. If that won't be the case, that's great, but if so, then maybe safer would be:

```
=VLOOKUP(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(" ",1,H$3:H$4,B14)," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[preceding::*=.]"),H$2:I$4,2)
```

Comment: Thanks a ton JvdV. Truly brilliant solution. The first solution works perfectly.